# Sennheiser ME66 vs Shure SM81

Tags: microphone

I'm about to make a short video and have available a Shure SM81 that I can borrow when I need it.

Is it worth it to buy the Sennheiser ME66 in this case?

What are the differences between them?

Is the SM81 actually a shotgun?

Is the SM81 suitable for recording for films like the ME66 is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SM81 is a great little mic. I've used it for acoustic instruments before, but for video production you want the ME66. 81 is a cardioid pattern, 66 is a true shotgun. Only way the 81 would give you usable audio would be in a very controlled environment.

Comment: :( Seems I'll have to buy one then..

Comment: I've ordered a Zoom H4n. Do you think I'll need a ME66 to get good speech recordings for the short film?

Comment: That is one of my set ups. You won't regret that combination.